# vim EasyTags, per file type tags command?

Tags: vim, tags, exuberant-ctags

I use the excellent [EasyTags](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags) plugin with vim.  My only problem with it is that Exuberant CTags does not support Haskell.  However, there are several programs which do generate Haskell vim tags files correctly and I already use the per file type tags file option in EasyTags.

Is there a way to tell EasyTags to use different ctags program on a per filetype basis?  I could write a wrapper script and set that as the global ctags program but would prefer a cleaner solution.

I've tried

```
:autocmd FileType haskell let g:easytags_cmd = '~/.cabal/bin/lushtags'
```

But EasyTags seems to attempt to query the ctags program for a list of supported languages so when I open a Haskell file with this option enabled I get an error.

`"Data/Csv/Conduit.hs" [RO] 51L, 1950C
Error detected while processing function xolox#easytags#register..xolox#easytags#get_tagsfi
le..xolox#easytags#supported_filetypes..34_check_filetype:
line    3:
E605: Exception not caught: Failed to get supported languages! (output: Usage: lushtags [op
tions] [--] )
Error detected while processing function xolox#easytags#register..xolox#easytags#get_tagsfi
le..xolox#easytags#supported_filetypes:
line   14:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing function xolox#easytags#register..xolox#easytags#get_tagsfi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fellow EasyTags user here, I always wanted that functionality, too (for [`jsctags`](http://doctorjs.org/)). I've implemented a [patch](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags/pull/40) that allows to configure separate executables for particular languages.

Until this is merged (unfortunately, there hasn't been any activity there in the past few months), you can use [my fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-easytags). The configuration would be something like this:

```
let g:easytags_languages = {
\   'haskell': {
\       'cmd': '~/.cabal/bin/lushtags',
\       'args': [],
\       'fileoutput_opt': '-f',
\       'stdout_opt': '-f-',
\       'recurse_flag': '-R'
\   }
\}
```

Comment: Cool that looks like exactly what I want.  I'll have to investigate a bit more, it doesn't work right out of the box but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Hi there, author of the vim-easytags plug-in here. I finally got around to merging Ingo's patch so given the right configuration (see Ingo's post) everything should work out of the box.